# Rails, selecting from a relation [assuming it works]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I am trying to build a relational database in rails, but I am having trouble.

Every song has a genre. Which belong to a different table.

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :genre, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50 }
  has_many :songlist
end

class Songlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50 }
  has_one :genre
end


def index
  @songs = Songlist.all
end
```

This way of displaying the genre is broken. I am not sure if the genre is working as it stands, if it is then how could I select the genre to display it?

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <p> <%= song.name %> | <%= song.genre %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot calling the member "genre" from the Genre class. Try with

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
  <p> <%= song.name %> | <%= song.genre.genre %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I do that I get a no such coumn! genres.songlist_id.I haven't inserted a genre. How can I associate a song with a genre?

Comment: Fist change `has_one :genre` by `belongs_to :genre`. Then remember that a songlist belongs to an genre and that genre has many songlist. That means that is not possible to have a genre.songlist_id. The way to create objects for this relationship is, for example: `my_genre = Genre.create(:genre => "My Genre")` then `my_songlist = Songlist.create(:name => "My Songlist", :genre => my_genre)`

Comment: ss = Songlist.create(:name => 'DeathClock', :genre => (Genre.first))
  Genre Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres" ORDER BY "genres"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute `genre_id'  .........is it possible that my migrations are broken?I don't have a specific column for genre id

Comment: Have you replaced `has_one :genre` by `belongs_to :genre` in the Songlist model? Also check your migrations - you should have the foreign key genre_id in your songlists table.

Comment: add_foreign_key :songlist, :genre_id ??

Comment: add_column :songlists, :genre_id, :integer